# Regular expression - Starting/ending with something specific and repeating pattern inbetween

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to write a regular expression that matches names with the following syntax.

```
"Show log 8006, Conan O'Brian talks about Freddy Mercury, Evan.R Wood, Chan Kong-sang and McDonald?, Great People."
```

Group 1: Conan O'Brian

Group 2: Freddy Mercury

Group 3: Evan.R Wood

Group 4: Chan Kong-sang

Group 5: McDonald?

The consistency is "Show log ????, 'Name' talks about 'Name' and 'Name', 'Topic'".

The amount of names can vary, there are a minimum of 3 names and no maximum.

Comment: You might as well a) give us your programming language and b) simply split on the `,` and trim.

Comment: I'm trying to learn Python, started last week. And I'm stuck trying to understand regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Python` is fantastic but don't hurt yourself by starting with regular expressions.
Your task is actually easier achieved without them:

```
string = """
Lorem ipsum 
Show log 8006, Conan O'Brian talks about Freddy Mercury, Evan.R Wood, Chan Kong-sang and McDonald?, Great People.
Lorem ipsum
"""

for line in string.split("\n"):
    if line.startswith('Show log'):
        parts = line.replace(' talks about ', ', ').replace(' and ', ', ').split(", ")
        print(parts[1:])
```

This yields

```
["Conan O'Brian", 'Freddy Mercury', 'Evan.R Wood', 'Chan Kong-sang', 'McDonald?', 'Great People.']
```

Comment: @JapexDoe: Then please provide additional lines or post a new question.